# iPhone User Agent

Tags: iphone, user-agent

I'm building an iPhone app, that basically just displays information from an rss feed, and drags in some extra info from a related web site.
I'm considering to put in some reporting code, eg the code provided by PinchMedia. I do have some issues with that, because I'll be monitoring users without consent.
So, I was wondering if it was possible to just take a look at the requests that are received by the rss provider.

In my code, I approach the feed as follows:

```
NSString * path = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/whatever";
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
```

Does the iPhone send any User Agent information to the server when opening that URL?
If so, can I alter it in such a way, that it would be easy to distinguish a call from my app from regular rss clients?

Thank you for your insights!

Answer (score 16):

For your reference, here's the User Agent string supplied by an iPhone running the 3.0 version of the OS:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16
```

As Nevan says, that should allow you to distinguish iPhone requests from other requests.

Answer (score 1):

It sends the name of the app with the version number. It looks very different than the string browsers send so it's easy to distinguish.

Comment: That sounds good. Do you have a link to any documentation on this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I just got it by making a request to my server and looking at the logs.